# When using Tor I have slower Internet

Tags: speed

Before using Tor my internet speed on Speedtest.net was 70 mb, but now it's just 10 mb.

How I can fix this?

Comment: When using Tor or when using the internet regularly?

Comment: You have to give us more details.
Is it the browser bundle you installed?
If so - then that has no effect what so ever on the rest of your system.
The tor browser bundle is a standalone application that does not affect anything system-wide.

Answer (score 2):

The nature of Tor means that your speed will be reduced, your traffic will be routed through several computers before it reaches the internet.

Either disable Tor, or find a VPN provider.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind also that Speedtest.net isn't the best speed metric for Tor.  First of all it requires Flash, which can give conflicting data and should NOT be installed on Tor Browser.  Secondly, even if it picks up on a node near the exit, your speed depends on the speed of the exit node.

To reiterate the other answer, you're sacrificing speed for security.  **There is no "fix"; your connection is running at the speed of the slowest connection in the chain**.  If your speed is unbearable, you could have a bad "link"; try restarting the browser or creating a new identity.

Oh, and uninstall Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that the way tor works(to ultimately protect you) is by sending your traffic through nodes in the tor network finally exiting on a relay node. This process will naturally cause a higher delay, for which you will experience slower INTERNET. Also as was previously commented, speedtest is not a good way to test the internet, since it will not see your actually IP address, but the one at the exit node. Remember that this does not means your internet speed is lowered.. but is just a reflect that tor is doing it's work on protecting you.

Another fact, is that tor's speed might improve with more users acting as relay nodes, so please spread the word so Tor can do a better job on keeping us safe.